# Why do I get a different file when Saving the "View Source" page in Chrome compared to what I see?

Tags: google-chrome, source-code

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in Chrome, this will open up the Page Source. If you **copy and paste** this into Notepad and save it, then go back to Chrome and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the page.

The page generated <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is significantly larger:

[image]

Why are the files different? I would expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> would just save the HTML I see on my screen; the same HTML I get when I copy and paste it into Notepad.

I need to get the HTML from some forum posts and I've been manually going through and saving the HTML one thread at a time, but I just found I need to save about 6x as many as I've done already. This is very tedious, I'd be great if I could at least utilize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or some sort of browser plugin to automatically save the HTML that I would get as if I manually did View Source -> Select All -> Copy -> Paste into Notepad -> Save.

Comment: when javascript executes in the page, it may draw in additional code and markup from remote sources. This code/content is only present if the page is rendered, so a simple source view of the page only contains a portion of the runtime content.

Comment: Or the reverse of what @FrankThomas suggests, the "Saved" version contains all the code needed for the page, where as the "Copied" version is (probably) smaller because JavaScript removed/hid lots of elements from that specific view of the page.